# Trying to add numbers from a file into an array then print the array in formatted columns in java

Tags: java, arrays, formatting, file-import

I am new to programming and I am having some trouble taking a file with a list of numbers and converting it to an array of integers that I can then print in formatted columns (5 rows and 10 columns). I think I did the import correct using an `ArrayList` but when I try to print the columns I run into issues. I think I need to use a for loop to get the columns to print but I'm not 100% sure. Any amount of help would be greatly appreciated! Here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Numbers {

    private List < Integer > data = new ArrayList < Integer > (); //Create ArrayList

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filename = "C/Users/s/Desktop/file4/Input.txt";

        Numbers rfe = new Numbers();
        rfe.readFile(filename);
    }



    private void readFile(String name) {
        String input;

        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(name))) {

            while ((input = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                data.add(Integer.parseInt(input)); //Add each parsed number to the arraylist
                int[] i = input;

                for (i; i < null; i++) {
                    System.out.format("%20s, %10s", i);
                }

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {

        } catch (IOException ioe) {

        } catch (Exception ex) { // Not required, but a good practice
            ex.printStackTrace(); //Usually good for general handling
        }
    }
}
```

this is what the file contains (each number in a line):

```
32
73
63
47
72
34
26
84
27
75
95
10
48
88
28
65
71
40
14
11
67
76
77
80
12
15
30
74
13
41
21
22
57
17
99
92
52
38
18
46
62
64
39
16
43
29
79
49
19
60
```

Comment: What's the specific problem you're running into?

Comment: Formatting the code before posting it to StackOverflow would be a big plus.

Comment: this is the error that I receive       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int[]
 Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete ForInit
 The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) int[], null
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from int[] to int

 at Numbers.readFile(Numbers.java:28)
 at Numbers.main(Numbers.java:16)

Comment: Add it to your question! Your problem is far simple, you create a List of integers added the number to it but you are trying to get the number from another place `int []i` for loop your List outside the while

Comment: You should read some [basic java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems within your code. All of then at this portion:

```
while ((input = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    data.add(Integer.parseInt(input)); //Add each parsed number to the arraylist
    int[] i = input;

    for (i; i < null; i++) {
        System.out.format("%20s, %10s", i);
    }
}
```

First you did it right, you've added the readed number into your list: `data.add(Integer.parseInt(input));` and this is all you need for this requirement add the number from the file to your list so you just need this for your while:

```
while ((input = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    data.add(Integer.parseInt(input)); //Add each parsed number to the arraylist
}
```

After that you want to print it, the error you are seeing is because you are making a wrong assignment `int[] i = input;` forget about this, you don't need it.

You need to loop through your list to print all the numbers

```
for (int i=0; i<data.size(); i++){
    System.out.format("%20s, %10s", i); //here is your another problem
}
```

You want to print on that line two parameters `"%20s, %10s"` but you only give one so either print only one or pass the `i` twice:

```
System.out.format("%20s, %10s", i, i); //twice
```

Or

```
System.out.format("%10s", i); //just once
```

Comment: Thank you! this helped a bunch!!

Answer (score 0):

First you have to read the file,then add it to an Arraylist.Now you can easily display this my taing each values from the arraylist and one by one adding it to a multidimensional array.

```
ArrayList<Integer> data = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    String numberString="";

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    /*  while ((numberString = br.readLine()) != null) {

        }*/
        numberString=br.readLine();
        System.out.println(numberString);
        String[] numbersArray = numberString.split(" ");
        for(int i=0;i<numbersArray.length;i++){
            //System.out.println("array value-->"+numbersArray[i]);
            data.add(Integer.parseInt(numbersArray[i]));
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

At the below, I write and explain that what you try to do.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("C/Users/s/Desktop/file4/Input.txt");
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String line;
        List<Integer> intArr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { //reads the Input.txt line by line
           intArr.add(Integer.valueOf(line)); //adds int values(read from txt file) into ArrayList
           System.out.format("%10s", Integer.valueOf(line)); //it can print in your format while reading the integers
        }
        for (Integer integer : intArr) {
               System.out.format("%10s", integer); // or prints in a separate loop.
        }
    }
}
```